# Existence of time derivative in Bochner space $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U))$ (parabolic pde)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, bochner-spaces

Evans defines a function $u=[u(t)](x):=u(t,x)$,
\begin{equation}
u\in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U))\quad\text{with}\quad u'\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))
\end{equation}
as a weak solution of a certain parabolic initial/boundary-value problem (i.e. if
\begin{equation}
\langle u',v\rangle+B[u,v;t]=(f,v)\quad\text{for all }v\in H_0^1(U)
\end{equation}
and $u(0)=g$).

My question: The above time derivative $u'$ is understood in a distributional/weak sense, alright, but how do we know that $u'$ exists, or is this an implicit assumption? (This is from §7 in Evans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes，it is just the definition of the weak solution.  You can use many methods to show the existence of such weak solutions, say Galerkin method, which is exactly what Evans used in his book.  For a vector-valued function $u\in L^p(0,T;X)$, the weak derivative $u'$ is defined as the distribution $T(u)$ such that 
$$
\int_0^T T(u)vdt=-\int_0^T u v' dt\quad \forall v\in C_c^\infty((0,T)).
$$
Then we define $W^{1,p}(0,T;X)=\{u\in L^p(0,T;X); u'\in L^p(0,T;X)\}$. $ u'\in L^p(0,T;X)$ if and only if  there exits a $L^p$ function $u'$ such that for any $f\in X'$, the function $t\to \langle f, u(t)\rangle$ is absolutely continuous, and $\langle f, u'\rangle=\frac{d}{dt}\langle f, u(t)\rangle$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But still I wonder whether, when we define a weak solution of say a parabolic pde, do we impose a priori that $u'$ (as you defined it above) _exists_ and _then_, too, is in $L_p$?

Comment: And this is not obvious to me, because, when we think of $Lu=f$ in the weak sense (i.e. $B_L[u,\cdot]=\langle f,\cdot\rangle_{L^2}$ in $H^1$) with $L$ a differential operator of order $2$, the pde still makes sense even if $u$ just is in $H^1$, so in this case we don't need to assume $u\in H^2$.

Comment: @M.Charbonnier Yes, your first comment is correct. We want to find a $u \in L^2(0,T;H_0^1)$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ that solves the PDE in weak sense. A priori we don't know if this set of solutions is non-empty. Now, we reduce the PDE via Galerkin's method to an ODE which has a solution $u_m$. We find boundedness of $(u_m)$ in $L^2(0,T;H_0^1)$ and of $(u_m')$ in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ hence we define $u$ as the weak limit of $(u_{m_l})$ and $u'$ as the weak limit of $(u'_{m_l})$ - that means they exist! And it remains to prove that $u$ with $u'$ indeed solves the weak PDE. See Evans p.378.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Maybe you could check my latest question, also concerning weak derivatives in Bochner spaces.